# Access dynamically created anchor tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xmlhttprequest

I'm getting 'cars' array using xmlhttprequest and dynamically creating the anchor tags for each value in the array.

Now im not able to access the innerhtml of newly created anchor tags.

```
//script for getting array and creating anchor tags dynamically

var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {      
var cars = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
for (i = 0; i < cars.length; i++)
{
var mydiv = document.getElementById("myDiv");
var aTag = document.createElement('a');
aTag.setAttribute('href','#');
aTag.setAttribute('class','cl');
aTag.innerHTML = cars[i] + "<br>";
mydiv.appendChild(aTag);
}

}
};

xmlhttp.open("POST", "http://localhost:3000/welcomepage", true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
xmlhttp.send();


//script for accessing innerhtml of the above created anchor tags.

$('.cl').click(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
var t = $(this).text();
alert(t);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. use $.post instead of XMLHttp
2. use delegation [In jQuery, how to attach events to dynamic html elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359018/in-jquery-how-to-attach-events-to-dynamic-html-elements)
3. note how I use $.each

```js
//script for getting array and creating anchor tags dynamically
// not tested but should be ok depending on return values

$.post("http://localhost:3000/welcomepage", function(cars) {

  var $mydiv = $("#myDiv"),
    carHTML = [];
  $.each(cars, function(car) { // or function(_,car) - not clear from question
    carHTML.push($('<a/>', {
      'href': '#',
      'class': 'cl'
    }).html(car));
  });
  $mydiv.append(carHTML.join('<br/>'));
});

//script for accessing innerText of the above created anchor tags.

$("#myDiv").on("click", ".cl", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var t = $(this).text();
  alert(t);
});
```

Comment: I had to include $("#myDiv") . Worked with xmlhttp too.. Thank you so much...